# How do i achieve a target throughput of 65/hour for 1000 concurrent users over a period of 1 hour?

Tags: jmeter

I have a test plan with 1000 concurrent users over a period of 1 hr 20 minutes and has 4 different transactions linked to it. For one of the transaction, I am trying to achieve a target throughput of 65/hr. I tried this via Precise Throughput Timer but unable to get the desired results. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

This `calculator` (based on Little'Law) shows that the RT will need to be about **15 hours** to meet your requirement in terms of concurrent users (users currently at the SUT). I'm certain this is not what you are aiming for. Perhaps you should reformulate your question after rethinking the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the relevant configuration would be something like:

[image]

- 1 hour is 3600 seconds
- 1 hour 2 minutes is 4800 seconds
- if you need to maintain 65 transactions per hour for 1 hour 20 seconds it would be 86.6 transactions

Also be informed that you won't be able to apply the throughput to one transaction out of 4, JMeter threads model assumes that each thread waits for response from the previous sampler before starting the next one so all 4 requests will act at the speed of the "slowest" sampler so if you want to run requests at different throughputs it makes sense to consider moving them into separate [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

And last but not the least you may find [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin) easier to use as it doesn't require a lot of calculations, 65 requests per hour is approximately `0.01805` requests per second

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. Thats great help. I now only have 3 transactions in my thread group and I have placed the timer at the thread group level which means I will have to multiply 0.01805 by 3 right?